# First build in MyEclipse 2017 --> has errors in maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have the web project that run smoothly. But When on another colleague computer, it installed myEclipse 2017 and jdk 1.7. When first build the project, it shows error dialog with details as below. I have tried to new another workspace and delete the .m2/repository folder and update maven build. Same error dialog happened. It should be the environment issue. What should I fix it??

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'strut2_tiles_serialize_dac'.
assertion failed: Marker property value is too long: Problems encountered while deleting resources. (org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.6:war:default-war:package)

org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:795)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:750)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.internal.filtering.ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.deleteFilteredResources(ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.java:165)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.internal.filtering.ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.clean(ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.java:155)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.clean(MavenBuilderImpl.java:391)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$2.method(MavenBuilder.java:201)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$2.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:118)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:108)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:89)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.clean(MavenBuilder.java:223)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:737)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:551)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:529)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:112)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:460)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:346)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:343)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Contains: Could not delete '/strut2_tiles_serialize_dac/target/m2e-jee/web-resources'.
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Problems encountered while deleting resources.
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.delete(FileSystemResourceManager.java:370)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:358)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.standardDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.java:810)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.unprotectedDelete(Resource.java:1832)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:782)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.delete(Resource.java:750)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.internal.filtering.ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.deleteFilteredResources(ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.java:165)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.internal.filtering.ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.clean(ResourceFilteringBuildParticipant.java:155)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilderImpl.clean(MavenBuilderImpl.java:391)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$2.method(MavenBuilder.java:201)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$2.method(MavenBuilder.java:1)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:118)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:112)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod$1.call(MavenBuilder.java:108)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder$BuildMethod.execute(MavenBuilder.java:89)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.builder.MavenBuilder.clean(MavenBuilder.java:223)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:737)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:206)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:246)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:301)
                at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:304)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:263)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:403)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:551)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:529)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:112)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:460)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:346)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:343)
                at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Contains: Problems encountered while deleting files.
Contains: Could not delete: C:\Users\xxxxchan\Desktop\New folder\target\m2e-jee\web-resources\.svn\all-wcprops.
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\rwmchan\Desktop\New folder\target\m2e-jee\web-resources\.svn\all-wcprops
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
                at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.implDelete(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:269)
                at sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:108)
                at java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1165)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.internalDelete(LocalFile.java:218)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.internalDelete(LocalFile.java:238)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.internalDelete(LocalFile.java:238)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.filesystem.local.LocalFile.delete(LocalFile.java:136)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.DeleteVisitor.delete(DeleteVisitor.java:63)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.DeleteVisitor.visit(DeleteVisitor.java:151)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.UnifiedTree.accept(UnifiedTree.java:111)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.localstore.FileSystemResourceManager.delete(FileSystemResourceManager.java:367)
                at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceTree.internalDeleteFolder(ResourceTree.ja
```

Comment: Learn how to read stacktraces: `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:`

Answer (score 2):

Check if you've got write access to the following folder.

C:\Users\rwmchan\Desktop\New folder\target\m2e-jee\web-resources.svn\all-wcprops

Following exception is copied from your stack trace.

> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\rwmchan\Desktop\New
>   folder\target\m2e-jee\web-resources.svn\all-wcprops

Comment: After assigning permission to the all subfolders, it is working now. Thanks.

Comment: @AMMA Great & nice to hear.